# How to backup and restore manually created Docker networks

Tags: docker, docker-network

The command `docker network inspect` outputs all relevant the informations about networks. I am wondering, is there a way to restore networks from this json ?
Or, a tools that would allow to backup and restore the list of networks (and all their attributes : type, gateway, subnet, etc.) ?

(Context:  I am working on two different project that have conflicting ip addresses. They rely on externally created networks, but use custom install script that are not designed to  be called after everything installed)

Comment: A network doesn't really have properties that could be saved or restored; in most cases you'd just `docker network create some-name` with no options.  Stack Overflow is specifically for programming questions; can you [edit] your question to more clearly describe how this relates to the application code you're writing?

Comment: This question is about a "software tools commonly used by programmers, and a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" in my sense so I think I'm right to ask it here

Comment: I would like to restore the network and all its attribute : its kind (bridge, overlay, ipvlan etc.), gateway, address range etc.